# Deque implementation with array in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, object-oriented, queue, deque

I'm trying to implement a deque data structure with an iterator in Java using array. Please help to review and point out things that I can improve on.

```
public class Deque<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {


  private Item[] a; // the array.
  private int itemCount; // number of objects the array holds at any given point in time.
  private int head; //last filled position from Front
  private int tail; //last filled position from END
  private int size; // size of array.

   public Deque() {
      // construct an empty deque
      size = 2;
      a = (Item[])new Object[size];
      itemCount = 0;
      head = 0;
      tail = 0;
   }

   public boolean isEmpty()  {
                   // is the deque empty?
     return (itemCount == 0);
   }
   public int size()                        {
      // return the number of items on the deque
    return itemCount;
   }
   public void addFirst(Item item) {
     try {
       if (item == null) {
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("item cannot be null");
     }
   }
   catch (NullPointerException ex) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("item cannot be null");
   }
      if (isEmpty()) {
        addLast(item);
        //return;
      } else if (head == 0) {
        resize(size);
        head--;
        a[head] = item;
        itemCount++;
        //return;
      } else {
        head--;
        a[head] = item;
        itemCount++;
        //return;
      }
      return;
   }

   private void resize (int currentSize) {
     //resize array to squared of current size.
     int newSize = currentSize * currentSize;
     int newStart = (currentSize * (currentSize - 1))/2;
     int newHead = newStart;
     Item[] newA = (Item[]) new Object[newSize];
     for (int j = itemCount; j > 0; j--) {
       newA[newStart++] = a[head++];
     }
     head = newHead;
     tail = newStart - 1;
     size = newSize;
     a = newA;
     return;
   }

   public void addLast(Item item)   {


      if (isEmpty()) {
        tail++;
        a[tail] = item;
        head = tail;
        itemCount++;
        //return;
      }
      else if ( tail == (size -1)) {
        resize(size);
        tail++;
        a[tail] = item;
        itemCount++;
      }
      return;
   }
   public Item removeFirst()  {
      // remove and return the item from the front
      Item k;
      if (isEmpty()) throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException("Empty Deque");
      else {
        k = a[head];
        a[head] = null;
        head --;
        //start --;
        itemCount--;
      }
      return k;
   }
   public Item removeLast()  {
     // remove and return the item from the end
     Item k;
     if (isEmpty()) throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException("Empty Deque");
     else {
       k = a[tail];
       a[tail] = null;
       tail --;
       //end --;
       itemCount--;
     }
     return k;
   }
   public Iterator<Item> iterator() {
    // return an iterator over items in order from front to end
    return new DequeIterator();
   }
   private class DequeIterator implements Iterator<Item> {
     private int startpos;
     private int size;
     public DequeIterator () {
       startpos = head;
       size = itemCount;
     }
     public boolean hasNext() {
       return (size != 0);
     }
     public void remove() {
       throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
     }
     public Item next() {
       if (hasNext()) {
         size--;
         return a[startpos++];
       }
       throw new NoSuchElementException();
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a "[deque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue)"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pointless `try ... catch`:

```
 try {
   if (item == null) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("item cannot be null");
   }
 }
 catch (NullPointerException ex) {
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("item cannot be null");
 }
```

Nothing in the protected code can generate a `NullPointerException`.  Perhaps something did at one point, but that code was removed, and the `try ... catch` was not removed?

---

Missing argument check:

`addFirst()` protects against adding `null`, but `addLast()` does not.

---

Resizing:

```
private void resize (int currentSize) {
```

This is not a static member function, so it has access to the current `size` of your deque.  Why require the caller to pass in currentSize?

```
private void resize() {
  int currentSize = size;
```

... would be sufficient, and more friendly to the caller.

---

Resizing:

```
  int newSize = currentSize * currentSize;
```

You are *squaring* the current size???  Ok, going from 2 to 4 is fine, and 4 to 16 is within reason, and 16 to 256 could be justified, but 256 to 65536?  I won't even contemplate the next step!

Doubling is a perfectly reasonable, and quite sane, resizing strategy.

---

Resizing:

```
  for (int j = itemCount; j > 0; j--) {
    newA[newStart++] = a[head++];
  }
```

Copying element by element is entirely correct, but you could let the JVM do the heavy lifting.  There is a good chance it will be faster.

```
  System.arraycopy(a, head, newA, newStart, itemCount);
```

---

`DequeIterator`

You aren't protecting against any external modification to the deque while you are iterating over it.  Consider a deque containing one item, and call the `iter = iterator()` method.  Then, call `removeLast()`.  At this point, `iter.hasNext()` will return `true`, and `iter.next()` will return a `null`!

A simple fix is to maintain a modification counter in the deque class, and on every modification, increase it by one.  When you create an iterator, the iterator gets a copy of the modification counter's value.  On any iterator operation, compare the deque's current modification counter with the copy; if they are different, throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

---

Wasted space:

If your deque has space for 256 items, but only contains 100 items, if the items are all stored at the start or end of the storage array, then a call to `addFirst()` or `addLast()` might resize the array, growing it to 65536 entires, 65436 which will be empty.

Two options:

1) If there is still plenty of available space in the storage array, just move the current contents back to the "centre" of the storage array.  `System.arraycopy()` will do the heavy lifting here, avoiding any copy issue that may arise if the source and destination blocks overlap.

2) Use a circular array.  When you increment past the end of the storage array, you reset the index back to 0; when you decrement past the start of the storage array, you reset the index to the last element. `itemCount == size()` becomes the trigger condition to resize the storage array.  Take care to ensure you copy data from the src array to the destination array properly; you'll need to do it in two arraycopy() calls.

---

(Optional, Advanced) Type safety:

Your `Item[] a` array is not actually an `Item[]` array.  It is a `Object[]` array masquerading as an `Item[]` array, because it was cast to the desired type to force it into the desired member:

```
a = (Item[]) new Object[size];
```

This is fine, as long as the array *never, ever leaks out* of your Deque class.  For instance, don't ever add a `toArray()` method.

You **can** make a correctly typed storage array, as long as you are willing to pass the real item's class to the constructor.

```
public Deque(Class<Item> item_class) {
  size = 2;
  a = (Item[]) Array.newInstance(item_class, size);
  ...
```

You'd need this `item_class` in your `resize()` code as well, so store it as a member.

Comment: It has only been 6 hours since you posted your question.  You should wait before accepting an answer; others may have additional feedback.

Comment: Hi, @AJNeufeld  Thank you so much the valuable comments. I have implemented the improvements that you have suggested. May I post it as a new question for review or shall I put it as a edit to this question.

Comment: Don’t edit the code in this question; that invalidates any answers given to the question.  Yes, you may post a new question with your updated code, but include a link back stating it is a follow up to this question.

Comment: See [what should I do when someone answers my question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help. I'm a noob around here and I learned so much from this question and interaction. LEt me accept this answer and post a new question with (what i think is ) the improved code.